# MS Graph API returns 400 Bad request

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am using `HttpClient` to call Microsoft Graph and create a new Team. I am using the Beta version.

```
string TeamsName = objTeam.TeamsName.ToString();
string TeamsDescription = objTeam.TeamsDescription.ToString();

var objJson = new CreateTeamsJson
{
    templateodatabind = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teamsTemplates(\'educationClass\')",
    displayName = TeamsName,
    description = TeamsDescription

};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objJson, jsonSettings);
var modifiedjson = json.Replace("templateodatabind", "template@odata.bind");
StringContent postContent = new StringContent(modifiedjson, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TeamsName))
{

    TokenHelper tokenHelper = new TokenHelper();

    TokenResponse tokenResponse = tokenHelper.GetTokenAsync().Result;

    using(HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams");
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", tokenResponse.access_token);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        request.Content = postContent;

        var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
        var createdTeamDetails = response.Headers.Location;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            responseMessage = string.Format("Successfully created team - details: '{0}'", createdTeamDetails);
        }
        else
        {
            responseMessage = "ERROR: Failed to create Team.";
        }
    }

}
else
{
    log.Info("Please provide Teams Name");
    responseMessage = "Please provide Teams Name";
    IsError = true;
}
```

When I run the code I am getting a `400 - Bad Rrequest` at the following line:

```
var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
```

I tried the same endpoint and same JSON body request in Graph Explorer and I could create teams successfully. Can anybody help me?

Comment: You can try with something like Fiddler to analyze your requests and find the differences. To deal better with rest APIs you could also use some specific libraries, like RestSharp

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the Education endpoint (`POST /education/classes`)?

Comment: Could you please check using [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) if the auth token has all the required permissions? Also please try using fiddler to see the error message.